# ARM assembly float variables

Tags: math, variables, assembly, floating-point, arm

Im new to arm assembly and ive been learning a lot from this website [here](http://www.coranac.com/tonc/text/asm.htm).
At the end of this section [here](http://www.coranac.com/tonc/text/asm.htm#sec-gas) there its shows how to declare variables in assembly like so:

```
integer_array:
  .word 1,2,3,4
```

this works fine for integers but I need to be able to do this for floats and this:

```
float_array:
  .word 1.25,2.24,3.33
```

does not work, could someone show the correct way to declare float variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
.single 0e1.25, 0e2.24, 0e3.33
```

(or `.double`). See the gas manual for [flonums](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Flonums.html#Flonums).